# F# - Understanding types that use generics

Tags: generics, f#, polymorphism

I am having an F# exam in 10 days and as I am currently doing old exam sets, I ran into a problem understanding generics and especially types that have two polymorphic arguments.

The questions should be rather easy to solve, but how it works syntactically, I am not sure.
The old exam question is as follows:

The following type `Sum<'a,'b>` comprises two different kinds of values

```
type Sum<'a,'b> = 
| Left of 'a
| Right of 'b
```

Now I need to write two values of type `Sum<int list, bool option>`, one should be defined using `Left` and the other `Right`.

If you define `let sum1 = Left "Hello World` it evaluates to `val sum1 : Sum<string,'a>`, but I cannot find a way to create `Sum<int list, bool option>`.

How would you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you were to write

```
let sum1 = Sum<string,int>.Left "Hello World"
```

you would get a `Sum<string,int>`

so if you need a `Sum<int list, bool option>` then.....

(to be fair, in real life, having a `Sum<string,'a>` is not really an issue as 'a can become anything and if it needs to be a `bool option` or whatever, the type inference will usually do the hard work for you and constrain 'a).