# Polymorphic type inference in F#

Tags: f#, polymorphism

I'm trying to learn F# and have the following exercise

[image]

In the declaration of `type Sum<'a, 'b>` Left and Right is only composed of one value `'a` or `'b`. Thus, as far as I can tell, it's not possible to give two values in in the Left and Right constructors as question 1.1 asks. I've tried to specify two values in the following ways

```
let tmp = Left [4] true // giving two values, obviously failing
let tmp = Left ([4], true) // This returns just the first element as a tuple
```

The first gives a compiler error, and the second returns the type `Sum<(int list * bool),'a>`, still not specifying the second value in `Sum`

How do I proceed with this exercise? Any sources or pointers would be greatly appreciated, as I am pretty lost.

Comment: this question was asked 8 days ago

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61816967/f-understanding-types-that-use-generics

Comment: the other way to do it is to create a value, but TELL the compiler using a type declaration, what the type should be